# Javascript opening maximized window when unintended

Tags: javascript, window.open

Hey. The following line was opening a 490x610 window, but after modifying some other code, it started to open up the full page new window.  Any ideas as to why?

```
<a href="cart_display.php"
 onclick="window.open('uploader/upload_files.php?order_id=32063700',
 '','width=490,height=610')">Upload Here</a>
```

Comment: Please don't show us the PHP... Show us the outputted HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cart_display.php` is going to open since you do not `return false` in your `onclick` handler. Doing this will prevent the default behavior of the `onclick`, which is to follow the `href`.